# Node.js Projects for beginners

Tags: node.js

I'm a novice web developer without a formal CS background. I recently learned Node.js and was wondering if anyone knows any projects that are simple enough for beginners.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I like to point beginners to http://nodeschool.io/.